# Microsoft PixelSense ScatterviewItem Rotate event

Tags: rotation, pixelsense, scatterview

As the ScatterView offers built-in rotation, resize and movement actions it is quite handy for standard manipulations of Shapes. In order to provide a redo/undo I'd like to save the shape's settings to revert to a previous state, if needed. Therefore it would be nice if there were any events like "OrientationChanged", "Moved" etc. to hook up. I know there is the OnManipulationStarted-event but then I'd need to figure out whether its manipulation is kind of rotation, movement or resizing.

Is there a more elegant way than storing all attributes at each OnManipulationStarted-event?

Answer (score 0):

Orientation is a "dependency property" and WPF has a mechanism for letting you get "changed" events from any dependency property.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/03/05/listening-to-dependencyproperty-changes.aspx for a decent starting point.